# awk getline not working as expected on first loop iteration

Tags: awk

Consider this simple awk calculator program and its output

```
$ awk '{while (getline) {n=0;for(i=NF;i>0;i--)n+=$i; print "sum: " n;}}'
1 1
2 2
sum: 4
3 3
sum: 6
```

Note how the first input line `1 1` produces no sum.  All successive lines work as expected.  Why is no sum being printed for the first line of input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `getline` throws away the first line.  Try instead:

```
awk '{n=0;for(i=NF;i>0;i--)n+=$i; print "sum: " n;}'
```

By its nature, `awk` will iterate over input lines implicitly.  Consequently, the code `n=0;for(i=NF;i>0;i--)n+=$i; print "sum: " n;` will be run for every line of input.  There is no need here to explicitly loop over the lines.